# Report Filter for CloseDate is from Past Month

Tags: apex, reporting, formula, filters, validation-rule

I have following Formula on my Validation Rules, I want to find out which of my Existing Records comes under these validation rules, So, I am creating Report for it. I am unable to FILTER Following Critieria (Google Search didn't worked too much well for me here) ..

Need help in creating Filter Criteria for following

```
CloseDate < DATE( YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1) )
```

> I think this should work :  CloseDate Equals LAST MONTH

Comment: Will this work : CloseDate Equals Last Month

Answer (score 1):

You would actually want to use  one of the following:

> Close Date less or equal LAST MONTH

or

> Close Date less than THIS MONTH

The criteria you have in your question will only find items in November and nothing before that. You will not be able to use the Date Range when creating the report but instead will want to add a field filter.
[image]
Additional information regarding Relative Date Values can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US).

> Relative Date Value   Range
>
> YESTERDAY Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the day before the current day
>   and continues for 24 hours.
>
> TODAY Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the current day and continues for 24
>   hours.
>
> TOMORROW  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the day after the current day and
>   continues for 24 hours.
>
> LAST WEEK Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the week before
>   the current week and continues for seven days.
>
> THIS WEEK Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the current week
>   and continues for seven days.
>
> NEXT WEEK Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the week after
>   the current week and continues for seven days.
>
> LAST n WEEKS  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the week that
>   started n weeks before the current week, and continues up to 11:59 p.m
>   on the last day of the week before the current week.
>
> NEXT n WEEKS  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the week
>   after the current week and continues for n times seven days.
>
> n WEEKS AGO   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the week that
>   started n weeks before the start of the current week and continues for
>   seven days.
>
> LAST MONTH    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the month
>   before the current month and continues for all the days of that month.
>
> THIS MONTH    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the current
>   month and continues for all the days of that month.
>
> NEXT n MONTHS Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the month
>   after the current month and continues until the end of the nth month.
>
> LAST n MONTHS Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the month
>   that started n months before the current month and continues up to
>   11:59 p.m on the last day of the month before the current month.
>
> n MONTHS AGO  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the month
>   that started n months before the start of the current month and
>   continues for all the days of that month.
>
> NEXT MONTH    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the month after
>   the current month and continues for all the days of that month.
>
> LAST 90 DAYS  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. 90 days before the current day
>   and continues up to the current second. (The range includes today.)
>
> NEXT 90 DAYS  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the day after the current day
>   and continues for 90 days. (The range does not include today.)
>
> LAST n DAYS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. n days before the current day and
>   continues up to the current second. (The range includes today.)
>
> NEXT n DAYS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the next day and continues for
>   the next n days. (The range does not include today.)
>
> n DAYS AGO    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the day n days before the
>   current day and continues for 24 hours. (The range does not include
>   today.)
>
> LAST QUARTER  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the calendar
>   quarter before the current calendar quarter and continues to the end
>   of that quarter.
>
> THIS QUARTER  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the current
>   calendar quarter and continues to the end of the quarter.
>
> NEXT QUARTER  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the calendar
>   quarter after the current calendar quarter and continues to the end of
>   that quarter.
>
> LAST n QUARTERS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   calendar quarter n quarters ago and continues to the end of the
>   calendar quarter before the current quarter. (The range does not
>   include the current quarter.)
>
> NEXT n QUARTERS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   calendar quarter after the current quarter and continues to the end of
>   the calendar quarter n quarters in the future. (The range does not
>   include the current quarter.)
>
> n QUARTERS AGO    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   calendar quarter n quarters before the current calendar quarter and
>   continues to the end of that quarter.
>
> LAST YEAR Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on January 1 of the year before the
>   current year and continues through the end of December 31 of that
>   year.
>
> THIS YEAR Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on January 1 of the current year and
>   continues through the end of December 31 of the current year.
>
> NEXT YEAR Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on January 1 of the year after the
>   current year and continues through the end of December 31 of that
>   year.
>
> n YEARS AGO   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on January 1 of the calendar year
>   n years before the current calendar year and continues through the end
>   of December 31 of that year.
>
> LAST n YEARS  Starts at 12:00:00 am on January 1, n+1 years ago. The
>   range ends on December 31 of the year before the current year.
>
> NEXT n YEARS  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on January 1 of the year after
>   the current year and continues through the end of December 31 of the
>   nth year.
>
> LAST FISCAL QUARTER   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal quarter before the current fiscal quarter and continues through
>   the last day of that fiscal quarter. The fiscal quarter is defined in
>   Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> Note
>   None of the FISCAL literal date values are supported when creating
>   mobile custom views.
>
> THIS FISCAL QUARTER   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   current fiscal quarter and continues through the end of the last day
>   of the current fiscal quarter. The fiscal quarter is defined in Setup
>   at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> NEXT FISCAL QUARTER   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal quarter after the current fiscal quarter and continues through
>   the last day of that fiscal quarter. (The range does not include the
>   current quarter.) The fiscal quarter is defined in Setup at Company
>   Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> LAST n FISCAL QUARTERS    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal quarter n fiscal quarters ago and continues through the end of
>   the last day of the previous fiscal quarter. (The range does not
>   include the current fiscal quarter.) The fiscal quarter is defined in
>   Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> NEXT n FISCAL QUARTERS    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal quarter after the current fiscal quarter and continues through
>   the end of the last day of the nth fiscal quarter. (The range does not
>   include the current fiscal quarter.) The fiscal quarter is defined in
>   Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> n FISCAL QUARTERS AGO Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal quarter n fiscal quarters before the current fiscal quarter and
>   continues through the end of the last day of that fiscal quarter.
>
> LAST FISCAL YEAR  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal year before the current fiscal year and continues through the
>   end of the last day of that fiscal year. The fiscal year is defined in
>   Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> THIS FISCAL YEAR  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   current fiscal year and continues through the end of the last day of
>   the fiscal year. The fiscal year is defined in Setup at Company
>   Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> NEXT FISCAL YEAR  Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal year after the current fiscal year and continues through the
>   end of the last day of that fiscal year. The fiscal year is defined in
>   Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> LAST n FISCAL YEARS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal year n fiscal years ago and continues through the end of the
>   last day of the fiscal year before the current fiscal year. (The range
>   does not include the current fiscal year.) The fiscal year is defined
>   in Setup at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> NEXT n FISCAL YEARS   Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal year after the current fiscal year and continues through the
>   end of the last day of the nth fiscal year. (The range does not
>   include the current fiscal year.) The fiscal year is defined in Setup
>   at Company Profile | Fiscal Year.
>
> n FISCAL YEARS AGO    Starts at 12:00:00 a.m. on the first day of the
>   fiscal year n fiscal years ago and continues through the end of the
>   last day of that fiscal year.